# SVN : Ignore folder which have only property changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using SVN(tortoisesvn client) for source control. I have added propery for **Log Messages size**.
My problem is when I commit my file changes, There is all folder display in change list with status **status *modified (property change only)*** in my commit list.
How I can ignore this property change.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not and must not ignore this property-change, because SVN store and use not only data-change, but also property-changes in repository. When you set log message size, you changed property of folder, which must be stored in repository as commit (or part of commit) in order to be known later

Comment: Is there any way else ?